# Hibernate generate two many queries on Subselect one-2-many

Tags: hibernate, subquery

I am very happy with **SubSelect eager fetch**, but recently I got a problem . Here is my scenario: I have Parent table to many Children table. My hql is simple 
"from Parent" which should give 500 Parents with related Children..

- One first request : Hibernate generate 2 queries. So great, as expected !!
- One second request: It says each item of the 500 Parent is not 2nd level cache, and it generates 1 query for Parent, and 500 queries more to get Children for each Parent. Why ????
- OK, I applied EHCache Read-write on getChildren method. Hiberate go back to generating only 2 queries. BUT, only when to data is unchanged, if the data is changed, Hibernate keep generate 501 queries.

Above all, it doesnt make sense to me. I always expect only 2 queries for subselect , NO MATTER WHAT!!! Please help me! I am so depressed and my manager are thinking about going back to pure JDBC SQL